# T-SQL - Pivot by week

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I'm currently trying to create a T-SQL, which runs through a list of deliveries in a table, and groups them by the Customer and the Depot - so each row will be

Customer, Depot, Total Value (sum of a column called Rate)

However, the customer would like the 'total value' split into the last 9 weeks - so rather than total value, we'll have columns like this:

```
22/01/2012  29/01/2012  05/02/2012  12/02/2012  19/02/2012  26/02/2012  04/03/2012  11/03/2012  18/03/2012
```

The dates would of course change for when they run the query - it'll just be the last 9 weeks. They also want a column for the Average of all these.

I understand pivot may help me but I'm a bit stumped on how to do this. Here's my current query:

```
SELECT d.Name AS 'Depot, s.Name AS 'Customer', SUM(c.Rates) AS 'Total Value'
FROM Deliveries AS c INNER JOIN Account AS s ON c.Customer = s.ID
INNER JOIN Depots AS d ON c.CollectionDepot = d.Letter
GROUP BY d.Name, s.Name
```

Many thanks!

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of the data currently - we won't need the 'total' column on the end, just there to show you. The 'Date' column is present in the Deliveries table and is called TripDate

[image]

Comment: Can you supply us with the initial values and the output you want? Where is the date column present is it the `Deliveries` or the `Depots` table?

Comment: What version of TSQL?  SQL Server?  What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Question modified, thanks. We are running SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Chris OK thanks.  In the future it'll help to tag the Q with the version of software for clarity.

Comment: You're expecting a query whose column names (potentially) changes every time it's run - that means you're going to have to go down the dynamic SQL route, and it may not work well with whatever is consuming the result set. Could you instead have the column headings being e.g. "this week", "last week", "2 weeks ago", etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to make use of the PIVOT Keyword which is available in your version of SQL Server.  I have outlined how your query should look, of course some tweaking will be required since it is difficult to test without having a copy of your data.

```
  SELECT Depots.Name AS 'Depot',  Account.Name, '22/01/2012',  '29/01/2012',  '05/02/2012',  '12/02/2012',
   FROM 
(SELECT Name, 
    FROM Deliveries
    INNER JOIN Account ON Deliveries.Customer = Account.ID
    INNER JOIN Depots ON Account.CollectionDepot) AS Source
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Deliveries.Rates)
    FOR Date IN ('22/01/2012',  '29/01/2012',  '05/02/2012',  '12/02/2012')
) AS 'Pivot Table'
```

For reference you could use this as a guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: Thanks - the problem there is that the dates aren't hardcoded, these will change depending on the current date.

Comment: You could replace the hard coded dates with the actual Date field in your tables.  I would have included this in my example, however I was unsure of which field it would relate to in your schema.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing your exact data. It hard to predict what you are getting. But I can give you a suggestion of a solution.

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE Deliveries
(
    Customer INT,
    CollectionDepot INT,
    Rates FLOAT,
    TripDate DATETIME
)
CREATE TABLE Account
(
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    ID INT
)
CREATE TABLE Depots
(
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Letter INT
)
```

**Test data**

```
INSERT INTO Deliveries
VALUES
    (1,1,452,GETDATE()-10),
    (1,1,800,GETDATE()-30),
    (1,1,7895,GETDATE()-2),
    (1,1,451,GETDATE()-2),
    (1,1,478,GETDATE()-89),
    (1,1,4512,GETDATE()-31),
    (1,1,782,GETDATE()-20),
    (1,1,652,GETDATE()-5),
    (1,1,752,GETDATE()-452)

INSERT INTO Account
VALUES
    ('Customer 1',1)

INSERT INTO Depots
VALUES
    ('Depot 1',1)
```

**Table that contains the ranges and the formated date**

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME,
    FomatedDate VARCHAR(20)
)
```

**Calculate the date ranges**

```
;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT 0 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1+n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 8 )
INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT
    DATEADD(WEEK,-n-1,GETDATE()),
    DATEADD(WEEK,-n,GETDATE()),
    convert(varchar, DATEADD(WEEK,-n,GETDATE()), 112)
FROM
    Nbrs
ORDER BY
    -n
```

**The date columns for the pivot**

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ','+QUOTENAME(FomatedDate),
                     QUOTENAME(FomatedDate))
FROM 
    #tmp
```

**Declaring some dynamic sql and executing it**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)=
N'SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Depots.Name AS Depot, 
        Account.Name AS Customer, 
        Deliveries.Rates,
        tmp.FomatedDate,
        AVG(Deliveries.Rates) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) AS Average,
        SUM(Deliveries.Rates) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) AS Total
    FROM 
        Deliveries
        JOIN Account 
            ON Deliveries.Customer = Account.ID
        JOIN Depots
            ON Deliveries.CollectionDepot = Depots.Letter
        JOIN #tmp AS tmp
            ON Deliveries.TripDate BETWEEN tmp.StartDate AND tmp.EndDate
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    AVG(rates)
    FOR FomatedDate IN ('+@cols+')
) AS pvt'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

And then cleaning up after myself.

```
DROP TABLE Deliveries
DROP TABLE Account
DROP TABLE Depots
DROP TABLE #tmp
```